# Facebook asynchronous onClick conversion not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, conversion-tracking

I'm trying to install a conversion pixel for Facebook ads, so that when a user click on one of my ads on Facebook, they are taken to my site and the conversion tracker tracks how many of these users sign up.

My sign up form uses AJAX so I have to use the asynchronous version of the conversion tracker, so when the user makes a successful signup, an event is fired off to Facebook and the counter is increased by 1.

However, this doesn't seem to happen...I view one of my ads on Facebook, sign up on my site, but I don't see an increase (even after waiting the stated hour it takes for it to register...)

Here is my code:

This is going in the `<head>`:

```
<script>(function() {
  var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
  if (!_fbq.loaded) {
  var fbds = document.createElement('script');
  fbds.async = true;
  fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
  _fbq.loaded = true;
  window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
  }
  })();
</script>
```

and then, in the AJAX success block:

```
var cd = {};
cd.value = '0.00';
cd.currency = "GBP";
window._fbq.push(['track', '6030344305258', cd]);
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Minor point, but are you supposed to be using the variable `cd` somewhere?

Comment: Hi Andy! Yeah, I was playing around with the code... `cd` is supposed to be in replace of `{'value':'0.00','currency':'GBP'}`. I'll update the code - Thanks :)

Comment: Silly question, but have you tried putting a console.log in your success block just to check it is definitely running that code?